# ipv6: I can ping only 1 interface within same network even with static route

Tags: cisco, routing, ipv6, gns3, route

```
This is how I set up a static route. 
R1(conf): ipv6 route 2004:DB8:2233:23::/64 2001:DB8:1122:12::2

With this, I can ping to 2004:DB8:2233:23::2 (S2/2 on R2) but not to 2004:DB8:2233:23::3 (S2/2 on R3)
```

Here is sh ipv6 int brief from:

```
**R1**

GigabitEthernet1/0     [up/up]
    FE80::C801:15FF:FEB9:1C
    2001:DB8:1234:1:C801:15FF:FEB9:1C
Serial2/1              [up/up]
    FE80::C801:15FF:FEB9:0
    2001:DB8:1122:12::1

**R2:**
Serial2/1              [up/up]
    FE80::C802:15FF:FEC8:0
    2001:DB8:1122:12::2
Serial2/2              [up/up]
    FE80::C802:15FF:FEC8:0
    2004:DB8:2233:23::2

sh ipv6 route from:
R1:
C   2001:DB8:1122:12::/64 [0/0]
     via Serial2/1, directly connected
L   2001:DB8:1122:12::1/128 [0/0]
     via Serial2/1, receive
C   2001:DB8:1234:1::/64 [0/0]
     via GigabitEthernet1/0, directly connected
L   2001:DB8:1234:1:C801:15FF:FEB9:1C/128 [0/0]
     via GigabitEthernet1/0, receive
S   2001:DB8:1234:4::/64 [1/0]
     via 2001:DB8:1122:12::2
S   2001:DB8:3344:34::/64 [1/0]
     via 2001:DB8:1122:12::2
S   2004:DB8:2233:23::/64 [1/0]
     via Serial2/1, directly connected
     via 2001:DB8:1122:12::2
L   FF00::/8 [0/0]

R2:
C   2001:DB8:1122:12::/64 [0/0]
     via Serial2/1, directly connected
L   2001:DB8:1122:12::2/128 [0/0]
     via Serial2/1, receive
S   2001:DB8:1234:4::/64 [1/0]
     via 2004:DB8:2233:23::3
S   2001:DB8:3344:34::/64 [1/0]
     via 2004:DB8:2233:23::3
C   2004:DB8:2233:23::/64 [0/0]
     via Serial2/2, directly connected
L   2004:DB8:2233:23::2/128 [0/0]
     via Serial2/2, receive
L   FF00::/8 [0/0]
     via Null0, receive
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that ping is bidirectional. You send out an ICMP echo request, and you hope to get back an ICMP echo reply. That means that the replying device must also have a route back to the original sender.

You did not include the R3 routing table, but it would seem that R3 does not have a route back to the source of the ICMP echo request. It is not enough that R1 knows how to reach the networks of R3, but r2 needs to know how to reach the networks of both R1 and R3, and just as important, R3 needs to know how to reach the networks of R1.

---

When you are looking for help here, you really need to include the full configurations of all the network devices.

Also, as you are seeing, static routing does not scale. You should use a routing protocol to exchange routing information among the routers, and it will automatically add or remove routes in each router. OSPFv3 can be used for IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem was because there wasn't routes from r3 to r1. And also I want to thank you for the suggestion about how to post a question here. It is a school project that at first I need to set up static routes then use OSPFv3 and with OSPFv3 I was fine. First I removed the static routes then set up OSPFv3 on all routers.